# Disable about:blank for Datatable print

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

How to disable `about:blank` part of datatable print functionality.
I want the print overlay to appear on same page instead of opening a new tab and displaying print data.

Please let me know if there is any option available to disable opening a new tab and just having the print overlay on same page.

```
 $('#example').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [ 'print' ]
 });
```

Comment: It is not possible. because you have pagination. All the record cannot fetch in same page. thats why it will open in new window and show the all the records. then print screen.

Comment: @Vel is it possible to disable it completely, I dont want to see all the records. I just want the print overlay? where i can select options as to which printer to choose

Comment: yes. it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code on click funtion.

you need to select table id `#example`

```
var printContents = document.getElementById("example").innerHTML;
 var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

 document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

 window.print();

 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```